# Entity Framework 6 and mysql TableDetails Strong typing exception

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, strong-typing

I am trying to generate my model classes from a mysql database schema, with EF6. I use the ado.net wizard database first approach and I get an exception that says :

> Unexpected exception occured when generating the model.
>   StrongTypingException:the value for column 'IsPrimaryKey' in table
>   TableDetails is DBNull.

Answer (score 5):

Run the following command on the MySQL DB and then try if this works.

set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=off'

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the MySQL Entity Framework provider does not work correctly with all combinations of Entity Framework version and MySQL version. I had the same error when trying to create a database first model for MySQL 5.7 and Entity Framework 5 or 6 (tried everything, like with and without adding the MySql.Data.Entity Nuget package). The only success I had was with MySQL 5.6 and Entity Framework 5 (without adding the MySql.Data.Entity Nuget package beforehand).

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31961646/ef6-mysql-strongtypingexception-when-column-is-not-pk) question.